# Why does build folder in Android Development studio grow to 1 GB when resulting compile file is 50 MB?

Tags: android, android-studio

The build folder grew to 1 GB when compile size is 50 MB using Android studio.  Why is this happening?  Is it normal?

Comment: It actually depends on what dependencies you might be using in your project. Many code generation libraries as well as other temporary build info. is stored in the folder which also helps in faster code compilation afaik.

Answer (score 0):

I think so, mine is like 3GB and the compile size of the build file is only 300 MB.